# How to use Async Await Upload file/Image Vue js/ Laravel Api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, file-upload, async-await

I have a form that will have to save the images and also other inputed data and I want to use Async and await going to the api.
this is the laravel controller

```
 public function addbusiness(Request $request){
  

     return response()->json(["message" => "up"]);
}
```

this is the vue js, this is my problem, i have errors in sending the data to the controller and the right way to pass it, what should i put when sending all the data to the controller using async await. and also save it to the database. It returns undefined.After the method post on the fetch api part, what to do next?

```
data() {
    return {
        items: [
            {
                rank_id: '1',
                product_name: 'Multi Handle Tote Bag with Kalesa Scenery',
                orders: 2500,
                sales: '₱ 350,000',
                rating: '5'
            },

        ],
        redirectChecked: false,
        dropdownIndex: null,
        selectedBarangay: 'Select Barangay',
        barangayList: ['Bangkal', 'Bel-Air', 'Carmona', 'Dasmariñas', 'Forbes Park'],
        searchQuery: '',
        termsAndConditions: false,
        addinfo: {},
        busname: '',
        bustype: '',
        email: '',
        contact: '',
        country: '',
        city: '',
        barangay: '',
        tin: '',
        address: '',
        clearance: '',
        contractlease: '',
        busregistration: '',
        liabilityinsurance: '',
        redirectweb: '',
        lease: '',
        clearance: '',
       
    };
},
```

this is the function

```
 methods: {
    upclearance(event){
        console.log(this.clearance = event.target.files[0])
    },
    uplease(event){
        console.log(this.contractlease = event.target.files[0])
    },
    upregistration(event){
        console.log(this.busregistration = event.target.files[0])
    },
 
    upinsurance(event){
        console.log(this.liabilityinsurance = event.target.files[0])
    },
    async addbusinfo(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('clearance', this.clearance, this.clearance.name);
         fd.append('contractlease', this.contractlease, this.contractlease.name);
         fd.append('busregistration', this.busregistration, this.busregistration.name);
     
           fd.append('liabilityinsurance', this.liabilityinsurance, this.liabilityinsurance.name);

   
       fd.append('busname', this.busname);
         fd.append('bustype', this.bustype);
          fd.append('email', this.email);
          fd.append('contact', this.contact);
          fd.append('country', this.country);
          fd.append('city', this.city);
          fd.append('barangay', this.barangay);
          fd.append('tin', this.tin);
          fd.append('address', this.address);
          

        console.log(this.busname);
        //console.log(fd);
         await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/addbusiness",{
                                     method: 'POST',
                                    data: fd,
                            
                                }).then(response => {
                                    console.log(response);
                                }).then(result => {
                                    console.log(result);
                                });


    }
},
```

Comment: "have errors in sending the data" - which errors? "returns undefined" - where?

Answer (score 0):

Content type in header is missing in your request.
Add content type in header like this.

`headers: { 'Content-Type': 'content/type' },`

Hope it's helpful.